Windows executable generated from Python script detectedas trojan by Windows Defender
I have done a small python app (version 3.9.13) to send information to webapi on portal application. Everything works fine; until I try to make an executable file. I did it using virtualenv and pyinstaller with --onefile --noconsole appname and scriptfile.py.
The generated appname.exe is blocked by Windows Defender; classifying it as a:

Program:Win32/Wacapew.C!ml

I think is a false positive; but I cannot deploy on customer site with this issue. I have got no warning running python script from my own command line.
This is the list of installed packages:

certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
distlib==0.3.8
filelock==3.13.3
idna==3.6
platformdirs==4.2.0
pydeps==1.12.20
requests==2.31.0
stdlib-list==0.10.0
urllib3==2.2.1
virtualenv==20.25.1

At the beginning using Python 3.12. I've got .exe file in quarantine.
Moving back python 3.9.13 (which should be compatible with pyinstaller) I have just 8 sites of 72 on virustotal where my application looks infected.
Without --onefile option I have got just 7 sites out of 72 on virustotal where my application looks infected.
Any ideas? Thank you.
Angelo

angeloa63 is a new contributor to this site. Be nice. Take care in commenting. Check out our Code of Conduct.

Duplicate of Windows Defender detecting Python EXE as Trojan

Does this answer your question? Windows Defender detecting Python EXE as Trojan

It looks like there are no solution. So I setup an exclusion on Windows defender in order to do not have the warning now and in the future. It is not clean but better than nothing.

It's because it doesn't actually create Windows application per se.
The program is extracting a binary, and then running it.
From How the One-File Program Works

How the One-File Program Works
The bootloader is the heart of the one-file bundle also. When started
it creates a temporary folder in the appropriate temp-folder location
for this OS. The folder is named _MEIxxxxxx, where xxxxxx is a random
number.
The one executable file contains an embedded archive of all the Python
modules used by your script, as well as compressed copies of any
non-Python support files (e.g. .so files). The bootloader uncompresses
the support files and writes copies into the the temporary folder.
This can take a little time. That is why a one-file app is a little
slower to start than a one-folder app.

That is suspicious; which is why anti-virus applications give the false-positive.
Which is actually kind of instructive; i didn't realize that it didn't create a native Windows application. I assumed it compiled the python code to native x86 machine code. I assumed wrong.

Thank you Ian and sorry if my english is not good enough :-) Now I understood why the .exe gives false-positive. Do you have any suggestion to make a deploy package easy to install and without the false-positive issue? Thank you. Angelo

I really do not have any idea how to solve it. It seems it's a long-standing issue, and nobody has every successfully compiled python code to a Windows .exe executable. You may have to live with it, and tell customers to ignore the warning. It's an awful solution; i know.

Thank you Ian, I've set an exclusion of the .exe file on Windows Defender in order to do not have the warning popping up everytime... bad workaround but effective. Thank you and have a nice day
